# WPF application that uses LocalDb and entity framework not working on other pc

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I have a WPF application that uses LocalDb and entity framework. This works fine on my development pc but I have not been able to get it to work when deployed to another pc. I get error: "The underlying provider failed on Open."

My connectionString:

```
<add name="TeniPrevoziDBEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/fakturiranjeDB.csdl|
                                res://*/fakturiranjeDB.ssdl|
                                res://*/fakturiranjeDB.msl;
                                provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                                provider connection string=&quot;
                                data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                                attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\TeniPrevoziDB.mdf;
                                integrated security=True;
                                connect timeout=30;
                                MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Do you have localdb installed on the other pc?

Comment: Yes is in aplication directory. If I share this(aplication) directory and run aplication from my developer PC it works.